# Problema onde tenho que criar um retângulo sem preenchimento, mas estou com problema nos espaços adicionais no retângulo

Tags: python

Olá, tenho que fazer um retângulo sem preenchimento, exemplo:

```
digite a largura: 10
digite a altura: 3
##########
#        #
##########`
```

Mas, por conta do corretor automático do curso, não estou conseguindo prosseguir por conta de dois espaços no lado direito no meio do retângulo, exemplo:

```
##########
#        #[ESPAÇO][ESPAÇO]
##########
```

Não estou sabendo como solucionar esse problema, esse aqui é o código:

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))
    
def retangulo(largura, altura): 
    linha = 1
    while linha <= altura:
        coluna = 1
        while coluna <= largura:
            if linha == 1 or linha == altura or coluna == 1 or coluna == largura - 1:
                print("#", end="")
            if 1 < linha < altura:
                print(" ", end="")
            coluna += 1
        print()
        linha += 1
        

print(retangulo(largura, altura))
```

Answer (score 1):

São três os equívocos:

1. Da forma que a função foi construída a linha:
   `print(retangulo(largura, altura))`
   é prolixa pois todo o processo de impressão ocorre dentro da própria função `retangulo` então ela pode ser chamada diretamente sem a necessidade do `print()` .
2. A restrição na condição `coluna == largura - 1` é um contrassenso por como começa contar as colunas a partir do 1 sua última coluna terá como índice a própria largura.
3. A condição `1 < linha < altura` é uma gambiarra para corrigir erro gerado pela condição anterior e portanto pode ser excluida.

Identificados os problemas e modificando seu código para funcionar como deseja, ficará assim:

```
def retangulo(largura, altura): 
    linha = 1
    while linha <= altura:
        coluna = 1
        while coluna <= largura:
            if linha == 1 or linha == altura or coluna == 1 or coluna == largura:
                print("#", end="")
            else:
                print(" ", end="")
            coluna += 1
        print()
        linha += 1  
            
retangulo(largura, altura)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/Retangulo1#main.py)</sup>

Como, diz o [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero), funcionar não é o mesmo que estar certo, o seu código pode ser reescrito e simplificado com um [range](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#func-range), [f-string](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) e o operador de [repetição de sequencia *](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

def retangulo(largura, altura): 
  #Itera em l de 0 até altura - 1...
  for l in range(altura):
    if l == 0 or l == altura - 1:
      print("#"*largura)             #...se a linha for ou topo ou a base imprime quantos # quanto largura.
    else:
      print(f"#{' '*(largura-2)}#")  #...para todas as outras linhas imprime a primeira e última colunas.

retangulo(largura, altura)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/Retangulo2#main.py)</sup>

Ou então usando o [operador ternário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=tern%C3%A1rio#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator):

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

def retangulo(largura, altura): 
    for l in range(altura):
      print("#"*largura if l == 0 or l == altura - 1 else f"#{' '*(largura-2)}#")

retangulo(largura, altura)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/Retangulo3#main.py)</sup>